# Clear button in jquery datetimepicker addon

Tags: jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker

I have the datetimepicker addon

everytime when i select on a date... clear button got hide.... following is the code for

```
$( ".dateTimePicker" ).datetimepicker({
      showButtonPanel: true,
      beforeShow: function( input ) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          var buttonPane = $( input ).datepicker( "widget" ).find( ".ui-datepicker-buttonpane" );          
          $( "<button >", {
            class:"ui-datepicker-close ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all",
            text: "Clear",          
             click: function() {
              input.value="";
            $.datepicker._hideDatepicker();
            }
          }).appendTo( buttonPane );
        }, 1 );
      }
    });
```